# EndpointConfiguration required to instantiate a Web Service SOAP client

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to consume a Web Service within a Xamarin Cross Platform application. Following are the steps I followed.

1). Go to 'Connected Services' > 'Add Connected Service' in the project.
2). Click on 'Microsoft WCF Reference Provider' and Configure a Web Service reference.

Then I try to consume the reference within the project as given in following code.

```
   public async Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsAsync()
   {
       wstmanx56SoapClient client = new wstmanx56SoapClient();
   }
```

Which is asking me to pass an argument called `EndpointConfiguration`.
Google gives me mixed results. What is `EndpointConfiguration` .?
What should I provide here.?

Comment: Did you go through all the steps listed here:    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Comment: Yes, followed exactly same steps.